# Jq extracting the name and the value of objects as an array

Tags: arrays, json, jq, key-value

I have this code and I need to get the keys and the values of the "filterFeatureGroup" object with JQ.

```
{
  "filterFeatureGroup": {
    "Hauttyp": [
      "Normal"
    ],
    "Deckkraft": [
      "Mittlere Deckkraft"
    ],
    "Grundfarbe": [
      "Grau"
    ],
    "Produkteigenschaften": [
      "Vegan"
    ],
    "Textur / Konsistenz / Applikation": [
      "Stift"
    ]
  }
}
```

My desired output is:

```
[
  "Hauttyp: Normal",
  "Deckkraft: Mittlere Deckkraft",
  "Grundfarbe: Grau",
  "Produkteigenschaften: Vegan",
  "Textur / Konsistenz / Applikation: Stift"
]
```

I have tried to put together the keys[] and values[] of the object but then I ended up with multiplying the elements in the output.

```
jq ".filterFeatureGroup| (keys[]| split(",")) + (values[])| join(": ")"
```

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Hope folks don't mind me sharing this here (shout if you do and I'll remove it): I wrote up some thinking on the approaches to address this challenge https://qmacro.org/blog/posts/2022/12/28/learning-from-exploring-a-question-on-jq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have tried to put together the keys[] and values[] of the object

Use `to_entries` for that

```
.filterFeatureGroup | to_entries | map("\(.key): \(.value[0])")
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BnVDArifZrl)</sup>